# Add an event observer after customer enters his shipping adress in checkout

Tags: module, checkout, event-observer, magento-1, shipping-address

I want to add an event when a customer enters his shipping adress in checkout
I tried to create a module but it goes back to the cart 
here is as follows

`Observer.php`:

```
class Mantel_Shippingredirect_Model_Observer
{    
       public function controller_action_predispatch_checkout_onepage_saveBilling($observer)
        {
            $address = $observer->getCustomerAddress();
            if($address->getCountry() =='US'){
                              $observer->getRequest()->setParam('return_url','http://www.google.com/');
                             }

        }
}
?>
```

`config.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mantel_Shippingredirect>
            <version>0.1.0</version>    <!-- Version number of your module -->
        </Mantel_Shippingredirect>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <shippingredirect>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Mantel_Shippingredirect</module>
                    <frontName>shippingredirect</frontName>
                </args>
            </shippingredirect>
        </routers>
        </frontend>
        <global>
            <models>
              <mantelshippingredirect>
                <class>Mantel_Shippingredirect_Model</class>
              </mantelshippingredirect>
            </models>
            <events>                
                <controller_action_predispatch_checkout_onepage_saveBilling>
                    <observers>
                        <shippingredirect>
                            <type>singleton</type>
                            <class>mantelshippingredirect/observer</class>
                            <method>controller_action_predispatch_checkout_onepage_saveBilling</method>
                        </shippingredirect>
                    </observers>
                </controller_action_predispatch_checkout_onepage_saveBilling>
            </events>
        </global>       
</config>
```

and my `Mantel_Shippingredirect.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config>
  <modules>
    <Mantel_Shippingredirect>
    <active>true</active>
    <codePool>local</codePool>
    </Mantel_Shippingredirect>
  </modules>
 </config>
```

What is wrong? Please help me!!

Answer (score 1):

Your observer is never be called because of the model declaration.

You need to replace:

```
<class>shippingredirect/observer</class>
```

With:

```
<class>mantelshippingredirect/observer</class>
```

Another problem with the class declaration, you need to replace:

```
<class>Shippingredirect_Model</class>
```

With:

```
<class>Mantel_Shippingredirect_Model</class>
```

Comment: I tried and change the edit but still doesnt work

Comment: @user1619177 see my edited answer

Comment: i changed it but still not working maybe the observer is not correct? how can i check that it is called?

Comment: @user1619177 add some logs `Mage::log("test");` in your observer, enable the logs in the backend, try again and check var/log/system.log

Comment: I did it but nothing is showing up in the system:log I went to the checkout page , put in the details of my shipping adress and than next step and than went to check system:log

Comment: @user1619177 do a full checkout, I don't think the address is saved straight away. Also I suggest you test by adding an address to the customer from the backend and save the customer so you don't have to test via the checkout

Comment: I really wanted to check when a customer enters his adress if he is from the usa and if yes to redirect him to another website so I want the event to be after he puts in his shipping details and before the next step

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48229/discussion-between-user1619177-and-raphael-at-digital-pianism).

Comment: @user1619177 in that case I suggest you observe `controller_action_predispatch_checkout_onepage_saveBilling`

Comment: I made the changes but now there is a problem in the controller it redirects if it is and if it is not us to the cart page what could be the problem in the code?